# Getting Eclipse Java Organize Imports to work with Google checkstyle

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

So when I use the Ctrl+Shift+O shortcut to organize my Java imports it puts a space between packages that begin with a different root package. For example:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import work.enumeration.Generation;
```

This is incompatible with Google's checkstyle and I would like to fix this. I have tried going to *Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Edit > Blank Lines > Blank lines within compilation unit > Between import groups* and setting it to 0, but this has not fixed the Organize Imports action.

So I'm wondering how I go about resolving this. I would also like to set up Organize Imports to put a line between static and regular imports.

Comment: Just using a single '*' import group in the Organize Imports preference looks like it would do this. What a horrible style requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much @greg-449 , that worked. Also I can add a static import group "*" and that will keep the two groups separated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @greg-449 said in a comment on the question, adding a single "*" import group in the Organize Imports preference and deleting the existing ones (java, javax, com, org) will eliminate the single line spaces between packages.

As I said in the following comment, adding a single "*" static import group in the Organize Imports preference and placing it above the regular import group should keep the static imports and imports separated by one line.

The Organize Imports preference can be found at *Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Organize Imports*.

Comment: You may also need to configure the number of blank lines to be 1 under Blank Lines → Blank lines within compilation unit → Between import groups as per https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=534342#c2